# Razor View IF to a partial div

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, materialize

The thing is that Im trying to change background color of a div depending on an IF condition inside a foreach and I didnt wanted to make an entire replication of the code for every single condition(3 conditions actually).

My idea was to do something like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Models)
{

        @if (item.Status == "COMPLETED")
        {
            <div class="card teal darken-2 white-text">
                }
        @if (item.Status == "NOT STARTED")
                {
             <div class="card grey white-text">
                        }
        @if (item.Status == "RUNNING")
        {
            <div class="card blue white-text">
                }
                <div class="card content">

                </div>

            </div>
     </div>
}
```

But it seems that HTML detects the 3 divs with no closure and it crushes saying that the foreach needs an ending `}`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current code is failing because you are trying to mix C# code with plain text.

The `if` condition opens a C# code block. So if you want to mix plain text or html inside that, you need to use `@:` prefix. `@:` tells razor that the following is not C# code, but plain text. It is same as `<text></text>` tag

You also had an extra closing div.

This should work.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.SomeCollection)
{
    if (item.Status == "COMPLETED")
    {
        @:div class="card teal darken-2 white-text">
    }
    if (item.Status == "RUNNING")
    {
        @:div class="card grey white-text">
    }
    <div class="card content">@item.Name</div>
    @:</div>
}
```

**I personally prefer to add less C# code inside views. I like to keep my views more Htmly**. I would create a separate method which can return the css class you need based on the Status value.

Here is an extension method.

```
public static class UiExtensionMethods
{
    public static IHtmlString GetStatusClass(this string item)
    {
        switch (item)
        {
            case "COMPLETED":
                return MvcHtmlString.Create("teal darken-2 white-text");
            case "RUNNING":
                return MvcHtmlString.Create("blue white-text");
            default:
                return MvcHtmlString.Create("gray white-text");
        }
    }
}
```

Now all you have to do is, call this method in your view.

```
<div>
    @foreach (var item in Model.Tags)
    {
        <div class="card @item.Status.GetStatusClass()">
            <div class="card content">
                @item.Status
            </div>
        </div>    
    }
</div>
```

I created the extension method on `string`. You can create it on more specific type (Your Status class/Status type(enum?)/ The type of each item in your collection.)

Comment: Good answer, I was just about to also recommend calculating the CSS classes in a helper method.